Are numbers in sysfs presented in decimal or hex?
I am looking at files in sysfs, specifically in /sys/bus/usb/devices
The files contains small numbers, expressed as two characters, for example "00"
All of the examples that I have contain numbers that are "09" or lower.
I am writing a script to interpret these, and it is not clear to me whether I should expect "0A" or "10" as the next value (ie, is it decimal or hex?)
I've seen that these are views of kernel kobjects, but I haven't been able to find the source for where they're serialized.
Can you please tell me if those numbers (for example, in bInterfaceNumber) are meant to be decimal or hex, or if it varies on a case-by-case basis.  If it does vary, where in the source code can I go to check for specific files in sysfs?
If it is relevant, my computers are mostly Ubuntu, a mix of 20.04 and 22.04.  I went looking at the usb-devices script as a point of comparison and there have been changes between the versions that make me less confident of what it's trying to do.

it depends on the driver

It depends on the kobject field and its serialisation functions. It’s not always easy to find those, but for USB they’re conveniently grouped. bInterfaceNumber is declared thus:
usb_intf_attr(bInterfaceNumber, "%02x\n");

The second argument is the format string, so it shows a hex value. The line below shows that bAlternateSetting is displayed as a decimal value.
All sysfs entries are supposed to be documented, and bInterfaceNumber is described as
What:       /sys/bus/usb/devices/usbX/bInterfaceNumber
Description:
        Interface number, in hexadecimal.

